# Applying styling to certain buttons in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of buttons in a Tritter Bootstrap NavBar and I want to apply some special styling to some but not all.  I have a class from [BootSnip](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/stylish-button-list) but try as I might with selectors, I can't get it to apply to just the li's that I want.  It works fine if I apply it to the UL, but obviously that applies to all of them.

You can see I've got the class ds-btn on the third li down

I've tried changing the top line of CSS to
ul.ds-btn
ul.ds-btn li
ds-btn li

but to no avail. I'm probably missing something dead simple.

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar-right">
        <li class="people-button"><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "People")><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i><br />People</a></li>
        <li class="books-button"><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Books")><i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x"></i><br />Books</a></li>    
        <li class="review-button ds-btn">
            <a class="btn btn-lg" href="http://dotstrap.com/">
                <i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-2x"></i><span>User<br>Profile</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.ds-btn li { list-style:none; float:left; padding:10px; }
.ds-btn li a span{padding-left:15px;padding-right:5px;width:100%;display:inline-block; text-align:left;}
.ds-btn li a span small{width:100%; display:inline-block; text-align:left;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write css something like this

```
   li.ds-btn { 
          list-style:none; 
          float:left; 
          padding:10px; 
   }

   li.ds-btn a span{
          padding-left:15px;
          padding-right:5px;
          width:100%;
          display:inline-block; 
          text-align:left;
   }

   li.ds-btn a span small{
          width:100%; 
          display:inline-block; 
          text-align:left;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks and also to @Uriil and SW4 you're stars.

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors are in the wrong order, you need to use:

`li.ds-btn` ...

This is because you have the class `ds-btn` on your `li`, your current selector `.ds-btn li` is basically saying look for all `li` *within* any element with the class `ds-btn`, none of which exist in your code. `li.ds-btn` is basically saying look for any `li` *with* the class `ds-btn`

```
li.ds-btn { list-style:none; float:left; padding:10px; }
li.ds-btn a span{padding-left:15px;padding-right:5px;width:100%;display:inline-block; text-align:left;}
li.ds-btn a span small{width:100%; display:inline-block; text-align:left;
```